# lisbox1.selected index changed to -1 autometically

Tags: asp.net

I have a listbox in asp.net and I am binding list Items from database. I have a button named "submit". Now when pages loads I am getting desired values in listbox, but when I am selecting any value and pressing submit button it sets **listbox's selected index to -1.**

can anyone help me to get proper index value?

```
 <div class="PageRight">
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListOfSql" runat="server" SelectionMode="Single" DataTextField="sql_name"
            DataValueField="sql_text" Style="margin-left: 0px" Width="205px" EnableViewState="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListOfSql_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:ListBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPreSqlExe" runat="server" Text="Sumbit" 
        onclick="btnPreSqlExe_Click">
        </asp:Button>
     </div>
```

and .cs page is like

```
 protected void btnPreSqlExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            txtQuery.Text = ListOfSql.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

        }
```

To Bind Data in listBox I am using following Code

```
Private void loadSqlList()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string preSql = "select sql_name, sql_text from cn_sql_log order by sql_name";
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(preSql, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ListOfSql.DataSource = ds;
            ListOfSql.DataTextField = "Sql_Name";
            ListOfSql.DataValueField = "sql_Text";
            ListOfSql.DataBind();
            ListOfSql.SelectedIndex = 0;
            conn.Close();
        }
```

and calling **loadSqlList()** on page_load

Comment: give me your e-id i'll send you my complete code

Comment: :( I pasted my code there but don't knw how to share.

Comment: your session is expired.

Comment: I have updated in your account.

Comment: sir, if you give me your e-id I can send it as an text file to you.

Comment: Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     BKachhadiya@ismnet.com